# Python Pandas Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Datetime' when trying to create an average of time periods

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a dataframe (df) that creates a sample sums, means, and standard deviations of the following 12 monthly return series by month from another dataframe cdv file called QUESTION1DATA.csv and he head of performance data looks like this: [image].

So far I have created a code to find what I am looking for and have come up with this:

```
import time
df['Timestamp'] = portlist.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y') 

new_df = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).agg(['sum', 'mean', 'std'])
new_df.index.set_names(['Year', 'Month'], inplace = True)
new_df.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

However when I run this code I get this error and don't know where to go from there.

```
`"list' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

I

Comment: `portlist` is a `list`, not a `DataFrame`. `.to_datetime` is a `DataFrame` method.

Comment: `data['yyyymm'] = pd.to_datetime(data['yyyymm'])` then `data['year'] = data['yyyymm'].dt.year`. Or you can do `data['year'] = pd.to_datetime(data['yyyymm']).dt.year`. Also `,format='%Y'` is the existing format of the data, not the expected resulting format.

Answer (score 0):

`to_datetime` is available in `Pandas` and should be use as follows:

```
>>pd.to_datetime('13000101', format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
datetime.datetime(1300, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

In your case `portlist` is a list and hence the code is throwing error.

In your case it should be as follows:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y')
```

Comment: I see but when I try running this code it tells me pd is not defined

Comment: @Jake instead of pd write pandas. I referred your code and i think you have imported pandas using "import pandas". So you use pd instead of pandas

Comment: I basically import pandas using "import pandas as pd". So i use pd wherever I need.

Comment: Got it now I get this error when I run the code when there's no string in my dataset. "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: @Jake what is the data present in Year column of dataframe?

Comment: The year column dates the year of the portlist headers essentially. That's why I created the portlist variable to simplify the headers and its respective data.

Comment: @Jake is the column name yyyymm which you need to convert?

Comment: yes! that lists the range of dates needed with the corresponding headers and data depending on the year to get the mean and such.

Comment: @Jake Then add below statement and check
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymm'],format='%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: @Jake you are writing data instead of df. Right? Means : data['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['yyyymm'],format='%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: Yes but I keep getting this now "'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'year'" on the second line of the code I written